# Password Encryption Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am using encryption-with-pidcrypt npm to encrypt password.

It should input the username, password and public key and generates a encrypted password. but getting this error.

Uncaught ReferenceError: pidCryptUtil is not defined

login ts

```
let data = this.encService.passwordEncryption(this.guestPublicKey, this.loginForm.get('username')?.value, this.loginForm.get('password')?.value);
```

service

```
passwordEncryption = (
    publicKey: string,
    userName: string,
    password: string
  ) => {
    return Encrypt(publicKey, userName, password);
  };
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Le9H.jpg)

[service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmPrs.jpg)

[ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nm52Z.jpg)

Comment: can you show the `require` lines? is it possible that you haven't imported the relevant libraries in encrypt.js ?

Comment: I have imported encrypt in my service file where I am using this function. =>
import { Encrypt } from "encryption-with-pidcrypt";

Comment: seems like it's an outdated library, maybe just try using pidcrypt directly? or, try defining pidCryptUtil, I have no idea how, to be honest, but you can try something like this: `var pidCryptUtil = require("pidcrypt")`

Comment: Can you suggest me any lib to encrypt username, password and publickey ?

Comment: pidcrypt seems to do that, just use it directly, there's examples: https://github.com/nikvdp/pidcrypt

Comment: but I need to encrypt username, password and public key combine, how I will use this in pidcrypt directly ?

Comment: this seems to be the source code for encrypt function: https://pastebin.com/xm2kTQh5 - also I looked into it and guess it's something related to strict mode. can you try putting `window.pidCryptUtil = window.pidCryptUtil || null;` on index.js and see if it's fixed? source: https://github.com/nikvdp/pidcrypt/issues/6

Comment: After placing  **window.pidCryptUtil = window.pidCryptUtil || null; ** in my index.html file the error is removed but now its giving undefined. not returning a encrypted password

Comment: looks like the module adds `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----` and end for you already. it returns undefined if publickey couldn't be parsed. if it's another error, it will probably throw an exception. if you supply these in your code/inputs, try deleting them?